# Enlarge numpy image and fill extra space with zeros

Tags: python, image, numpy, computer-vision

I'm working with a list of images **image_list**. Each item in **image_list** is a numpy array with shape (X, Y, 3). X is the height, Y is the width, and each image has 3 colors channels.

I want to get the max width and height of all the images, and resize each image such that the bottom and right is filled with 0's if there's extra space. I can do the first part (getting max height and max width) but I'm struggling with the second (resizing and filling excess area on the right and bottom with zeros).

```
max_height = 0
max_width = 0
for image in image_list:
    shape = image.shape
    if shape[0] > max_height:
        max_height = shape[0]
    if shape[1] > max_width:
        max_width = shape[1]
```

To resize, I've tried:

```
image.resize((max_height, max_width, 3))
```

But that only sometimes works. Other times you get the same image repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach with `A` being the input list of images -

```
M,N = np.max([i.shape[:2] for i in A],0)
M_ext = [M-i.shape[0] for i in A]
N_ext = [N-i.shape[1] for i in A]
out = [img3D_pad(a,M_ext[i],N_ext[i]) for i,a in enumerate(A)]
```

Helper function -

```
def img3D_pad(a,m,n):
    return np.pad(a,((0,m),(0,n),(0,0)),'constant')
```

**Verification**

1) Shape verification :

```
In [108]: A = [np.random.randint(11,99,(4,5,3)), np.random.randint(11,99,(2,6,3))]

In [109]: [i.shape for i in out]
Out[109]: [(4, 6, 3), (4, 6, 3)]
```

2) Value verification :

```
In [110]: A[0][...,0]
Out[110]: 
array([[53, 64, 41, 13, 85],
       [74, 53, 88, 47, 54],
       [35, 26, 93, 68, 80],
       [38, 68, 50, 83, 77]])

In [111]: out[0][...,0]
Out[111]: 
array([[79, 33, 41, 16, 76,  0],
       [11, 49, 54, 56, 40,  0],
       [38, 43, 98, 95, 23,  0],
       [26, 26, 20, 59, 53,  0]])

In [112]: A[1][...,0]
Out[112]: 
array([[76, 44, 29, 20, 91, 71],
       [71, 90, 11, 51, 81, 22]])

In [113]: out[1][...,0]
Out[113]: 
array([[57, 11, 42, 95, 87, 75],
       [15, 70, 88, 88, 41, 95],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

---

**Approach #2**

Simplified one based on `zeros-initialization` -

```
M,N = np.max([i.shape[:2] for i in A],0)
out = [img3D_create(a,M,N) for i,a in enumerate(A)]
```

Helper function -

```
def img3D_create(a,M,N):
    p,q,r = a.shape
    out = np.zeros((M,N,r),dtype=a.dtype)
    out[:p,:q] = a
    return out
```